# removing `\n` using bs4 get_text()

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# current output as below
"""
'DOMINGUEZ, JONATHAN D. VS. RAMOS,\n
                                           SILVIA M'
"""

# desired one is

#  DOMINGUEZ, JONATHAN D. VS. RAMOS, SILVIA M

x = """<td width="350px" valign="top"
   style="padding:.5rem;">
   DOMINGUEZ, JONATHAN D. VS. RAMOS,
   SILVIA M
</td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('td').get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
```

I checked the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) and I believe that `get_text()` can do that but am not sure how!

Comment: I'm not aware `.get_text()` has this ability. However, you can process the string with `re`: `re.sub(r"\s{2,}", " ", soup.select_one("td").get_text(strip=True))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need a regular expression, this could also get rid of extra spaces:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

x = """<td width="350px" valign="top"
   style="padding:.5rem;">
   DOMINGUEZ, JONATHAN D. VS. RAMOS,
   SILVIA M
</td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml')
text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', soup.select_one('td').get_text(strip=True))
print(text)
```

Giving:

`DOMINGUEZ, JONATHAN D. VS. RAMOS, SILVIA M`

Answer (score 1):

change `separator='\n'` to `separator=' '`

Comment: Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Just to give some context - In this case `get_text(strip=True)` per se wont work cause, text in your `<td>` is not "separated" by tags and more precise not by `<br>`, so it would be recognized as one "multiline" string containing new line characters.

Resulting from this circumstance the parameter `strip=True` only strips characters left and right from the whole string.

---

Based on following HTML it would work your way with whitespace as seperator:

```
x = """<td width="350px" valign="top"
style="padding:.5rem;">
DOMINGUEZ, JONATHAN D. VS. RAMOS,<br> 
SILVIA M

</td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(x)
soup.td.get_text(' ',strip=True)
```

But without any tag included in the string as possible seperator I would recommend to use ***@Martin Evans*** answer using `regex` that also handles the multiple whitespaces very well.

```
re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', soup.select_one('td').get_text(strip=True))
```